# Making this reduce() Fibonacci generator better

Tags: python, fibonacci-sequence

I've recently discovered how cool `reduce()` could be and I want to do this:

```
>>> a = [1, 1] + [0] * 11
>>> count = 1
>>> def fib(x,n):
...     global count
...     r = x + n
...     if count < len(a) - 1: a[count+1] = r
...     count += 1
...     return r
>>>
>>> reduce(fib,a,1)
610
>>> a
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233]
```

But this just looks so messy and almost defeats the purpose of the last line:

```
reduce(fib,a,1)
```

What would be a better way to use Python to make a Fibonacci number with `reduce()`?

Comment: Why do you want to use reduce?

Comment: Because it seemed cool. I want to use something like reduce, or map. Because it seems like a challenge.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow It's not really the right tool for the job. A generator would be the best choice.

Comment: @Lattyware okay but a generator is just too easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `reduce` (that's it, a fold) is not exactly the abstraction for the task (what input collection are you going to fold here?). Anyway, you can cheat a little bit and fold the indexes even if you don't really use them within the folding function. This works for Python 2.x:

```
def next_fib((x, y), n):
    return (y, x + y)

reduce(next_fib, xrange(5), (1, 1))[0]
#=> 8
```

Comment: That is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

If you set

```
def fib(x, _):
    x.append(sum(x[-2:]))
    return x
```

then:

```
>>> reduce(fib, xrange(10), [1, 1])
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
```

But as long as you're looking for something cool rather than something useful, how about this? In Python 3.3:

```
from itertools import islice
from operator import add

def fib():
    yield 1
    yield 1
    yield from map(add, fib(), islice(fib(), 1, None))
```

Comment: I guess the second snippet tries to mimic Haskell's `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`. Unfortunately this is terribly inefficient in Python, you'd need to write it in more verbose manner using corecursion and `itertools.tee` (thus the beauty of the Haskell solution completely vanishes). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion

Comment: Yes: that's why I described it as "cool rather than useful"!

Comment: I like that a lot the second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the interesting part of `reduce` is to re-apply a function.
So, let's define :

```
>>> def ncompose(f, a, n): return a if n <= 0 else ncompose(f, f(a), n-1)
```

Then,

```
>>> def fibo((a,b)): return (b, a+b)
>>> ncompose(fibo, (1,1), 5)[0]
8
```

Since you like to play with `reduce`, let's use it to perform composition :

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,f: f(a), [fibo]*5, (1,1))
```

Like @tokland's answer, it's quite artificial (building n items only as a way to iterate n times).

A side note : Haskell and Scala should provide you even more fun'.